# How to automatically enable browser location setting in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, geolocation

I want to enable browser geolaction automatically, as i am getting a confirmation dialog while accessing geolocation to allow or deny, i dont want any confirmation dialog.
[image: Below is the scrreenshot of confirmation dialog while accessing geolocation in google chrome]

Comment: "i dont want any confirmation dialog." - users do though.

Comment: The confirmation dialog is to prevent websites from accessing data without the user being aware of it. You can't bypass it from your website, and that's a good thing imho

Comment: indeed @Stephen i agree but i want to forcefully access users geolocation, ain't there any way to customise the confirmation dialog as it has been provided by browsers

Comment: Well, I want to forcefully access the saved passwords in the browser of the users of my site. Still hoping the browser builders will oblige....

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible.
You can't force the browser to allow or deny a configuration (security reason)

Answer (score 0):

**Impossible**.  This is meant for **user's [PRIVACY POLICY](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/legal/privacy/firefox.html)**.

> **Geolocation** support is opt-in. That means your browser will never force you to reveal your current physical location to a remote server.
>   The user experience differs from browser to browser.

Which is known as [*Location-Aware Browsing*](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/geolocation/)

> Source from [**DiveIntoHTML5**](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html#divingin)
>
> **Q:** Geolocation sounds scary. Can I turn it off?
>
> **A:** Privacy is an obvious concern when you’re talking about sharing your physical location with a remote web server. The geolocation API
>   explicitly states: “User Agents must not send location information to
>   Web sites without the express permission of the user.” In other words,
>   sharing your location is always opt-in. If you don’t want to, you
>   don’t have to.

This is handled differently in each browsers, yet common in theory.

But you can handle it wisely using [**Modernizr**](http://modernizr.com/)

```
function get_location() {
  if (Modernizr.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);
  } else {
    // no native support; maybe try a fallback?
  }
}
```